# Python: load image data into an array with given image paths

Tags: python

I define a function to load image data into an array. My image sizes are all the same 200*200*3 (rgb images). I am going to load them into an array of the size N*200*200*3 where N is the number of images

The function I defined is:

```
def getImgData(imgPaths):
    #load image data
    from scipy import misc    
    imgData = [] #assume its shape is unknown
    for ii in range(len(imgPaths)):
        temp = misc.imread(imgPaths[ii])
        imgData[ii,:,:,:] = temp
    return imgData
```

The input imgPaths is a list each element in which is the absolute path of an image.

But the function does not work as expected because of the TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple. It seems there is something wrong with imgData = [] (it is not an array)

Anyone can help me solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line:

```
imgData[ii,:,:,:] = temp
```

I believe that this implementation is what you expected to get:

```
def getImgData(imgPaths):
     imgData = [misc.imread(path) for path in imgPaths]
     return imgData
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by array [N,200,200,3]? Array must have an index key and a value. I think that what you want is an array of array where each index in the array points to the array returned by misc.imread right?
this will give you

imgData[N] = image array.

I would right the following code:

```
def getImgData(imgPaths):
    #load image data
    from scipy import misc    
    imgData = [misc.imread(path) for path in imgPaths]
    return imgData
```